# Java - write to Kafka from Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I'm new to Kafka and Spark so in advance sorry if the question is considered stupid :).

I'm trying to understand how the data is processed exactly and cached (from Spark) before being written into Kafka.

Let's say we have the following code handling the code to be executed per partition (since we're using mapPartitions())

```
Dataset<String> resultsDF = scenarios.mapPartitions((MapPartitionsFunction<Obj1, String>) permutations -> {
            Iterable<Obj1> iterable = () -> permutations;
            return StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false).map(permutation -> {
                log.info("Do some work ....");
                return "abc";
            }).iterator();
        }, Encoders.STRING());
```

And later on I'm writing this dataset to Kafka using

```
        resultsDF
                .write()
                .format("kafka")
                .options(options)
                .save();
```

where options are kafka options like group.id, kafka.bootstrap.servers and topic

What I'm trying to understand is how the dataset is processed - is Spark going through the partitions, collecting all results from calculation and appending them to the dataset therefore generating a very large DS in memory? (I'm looking for the potential causes of out of memory errors).
And if yes, is there a clean way to write data to Kafka per partition processing instead of gathering everything into the Dataset first? Something like invoking write() directly within the mapPartitions function or something?

EDIT: I know data isn't actually processed until 'write()' is called, however, I'm still unclear on what this write actually writes - so how I can check the instruction plan for the dataset in more detail - I need to confirm that data is being written to kafka directly with each calculation rather than a bulk set after all calculations have finished.
I tried tracing app logs vs kafka logs but to be honest it wasn't really helpful - detailed kafka logs are available for the topic, but that one is only being created after I actually call write() (in my specific case the topic is being dynamically assigned just before processing the results)

Comment: From the [javadoc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html). "Datasets are "lazy", i.e. computations are only triggered when an action is invoked. Internally, a Dataset represents a logical plan that describes the computation required to produce the data.". So no, a `Dataset` contains instructions rather than data.

Comment: @Kayaman - I get that they're lazy, but I'm unclear on what happens exactly at the moment I invoke write() - I understand that that's the moment the data is actually getting processed according to the instruction plan, but how does this look like? The write is being invoked on the Dataset, so how can I figure out exactly how the instruction plan looks like? So how can I confirm that data is being written to kafka with each calculation when it's finally executed rather than caching it somewhere until all results are retrieved and the full set can be written to kafka?

Comment: Call `explain()` to see the plan. Considering that Spark is supposed to be a streaming platform, it would be quite poor form to wait until the data is completely processed before writing it. The [code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriter.scala) eventually executes a command on `SparkSession` to perform the work (insert/append/etc.), so it's up to Spark internals how it's handled (and presumably it tries to do it efficiently).

Comment: What is the schema of your dataframe, by the way?

Comment: Also, `group.id` is not a valid Kafka producer option (nor does it work in Spark's readStream options)